# How do I use combinational logic while using posedge?

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner at Verilog and I am trying to get logic to occur every positive clock edge. However, within this same block, I need combinational logic as I am using a for-loop and changing the value of a register within the for-loop. Currently, the value of this register always shows up as X. Is there a way to get this logic processed within a sequential block? Thanks!

Code:

```
output reg count;
// ...
always @(posedge clock) begin
    integer row;
    integer col;
    count <= 0;
    for (col = 0; col < 4; col = col + 1) begin
        if (col == 1)
            count <= count + 1;
        if (count == 1) begin
          //other logic that does not occur because count value = x
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Update: I was able to get logic to work with the use of integers and setting the value of an integer to what my count was supposed to be.  At the very end I set the value of my count register to the integer value.

Answer (score 3):

Non-blocking assignment works does not assign values immediately to the 'count'. Instead they postpone the assignment till the end of the simulation tick. So, in your case:

1. initially the value of the `count` is `x`.
2. in your always block `count <= 0` will set it to zero some time in the future, but for now it is still `x`;
3. in your loop you say `count <= count + 1`. But the `count` is still 'x' and `count + 1` is also `x`. You asked it to assign `x` to the count some time in the future, but after you asked it to assign '0'. So, it will become 'x' at the end of the simulation tick. As a result it will always be 'x'.
4. your `if (count == 1)` which will never be true, because `count` is still 'x'.

The usual way to initialize your count is to have a reset signal, for example

```
 always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset)
        count <= 0;
    else 
        for(...)
           if (col == 1) 
               count <= count + 1;
 end
```

you can add your `if (count == 1)` inside the always block, but remember the rule of the non-blocking assignments, count will become '1' one clock cycle later in this case. Depending on your requirements you might be able to move it into a separate always block.

```
  always @* 
     if (count == 1) do something
     else do something else
```